# Adding quotes to words using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace each word in a sentence with the same word but quote (by word I mean just letters, no numbers) using regex.

For example `4 python code` should be converted to `4 "python" "code"`.

But this code produce the wrong result

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "4 python code"
>>> re.sub(r'([a-z]*)', r'"\1"', s)
'""4"" "python" "code"'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how many times you will run this, and how important performance is, you may want to consider compiling your regex.  You may also want `\w` instead of `[a-z]` if you want caps - or you could use `[a-zA-Z]`.

```
>>> replacer = re.compile("(\w+)")
>>> replacer.sub(r'"\1"', "4 python code")
'"4" "python" "code"'
```

Comment: `\w` wouldn't work here for the OP's purposes as it's actually `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` - so you'd have to use your other suggestion `[a-zA-Z]`

Answer (score 3):

Change,

```
re.sub(r'([a-z]*)', r'"\1"', s)
```

to

```
re.sub(r'([a-z]+)', r'"\1"', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way without using `re`.

```
s = "4 python code"
new = " ".join([item if item.isdigit() else '"{}"'.format(item) for item in s.split()])
```